# invalid_client the oauth client was not found error

Tags: oauth, google-signin

If I just want to enable Oauth with goolge do I need to enable apis for that? 
If I do which ones do I need I just want to be able to use passthru authentication with oauth2, I have been looking at questions for hours trying to find a solution to this error. the only thing that doesn't look quite right is that the full client_id is not displayed in the error the url is a little longer.

```
401. That’s an error.
```

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.
Request Details

```
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback
scope=profile email
client_id= 404342589460-ig7nuv617skbfaestvsc1jrpqtnipvv2.apps.googleuserconte
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to enable apis. After copy values from Google web UI, remove **blank space** at the beginning and at the end of both client ID and secret.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer